# Automatically update aar files in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I recently considered migrating to Android Studio from Eclipse and of course I encountered difficulties. I managed to get past most of them but one...

In eclipse I would have used a library project which I would then add to each Eclipse project I wanted to use it in. When I updated the library, the effects were immediately visible in the other projects.

In android studio, the story is different. I managed to generate .aar files and import them in my projects. Trouble is, is there any way i can keep the .aar updated in all this projects without having to copy the files again for each one (obviously tedious). If not, is there any way to use library projects the way I was using them in eclipse? What I basically want is a way to automatically update my library changes in all projects that use it.

Comment: For me it worked to import the eclipse project which depends on the library project. Android Studio then imported this lib project as a module where I can work on.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, but again, I would have to keep a copy of this module in every project...

Comment: I found out how to do it properly! Check my answer below. Helpful for me as well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reference an existing library project (existent as an Android Studio project) you have to add the following lines to your settings.gradle file of your project where you want to link it.

```
include 'your-lib-project'
project(':your-lib-project').projectDir = new File('path/to/your/lib/project')
```

Additionally you need to add the project to the dependencies in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':your-lib-project')
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it but i get the error message: Project with path ':your-lib-project' could not be found in root project 'MyProject'.

Comment: Check that you choose the correct module and project name in the include. I got it working like this.

Comment: It behaves as if the library is missing. I wrote this: include 'module_catalog' \n 
project (':module_catalog').projectDir = new File('/Users/mconstantin/AndroidstudioProjects/ModuleCatalog')

Comment: Ok, i got it working. I forgot to add the imported project as a dependency. And the path is more like '/folder/../Workspace/Project/myMainModule' - it seems more clear to me.